# Clustered Index and PK - Two different Objects?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

I have a table which has a Clustered PK as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PanelCcmRawData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CcmRawData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CcmRawDataId] ASC,
    [LineageId] ASC
)
```

I understand that when you create a Clustered Index, the table itself is the clustered index. However, when you make the Clustered Index the PK as well, it seems SQL Server creates an actual index file. I noticed this because when I ran a query to see all the indexes on my table, the number of seeks on the index and the size etc., I saw an entry for PK_CcmRawData with a size of 331GB.

I was a bit surprised to see this. I'm curious why, when creating a Clustered Index that is also the PK, SQL Server creates an index file. I would have thought the table itself would act as the Clustered Index and PK. So there appears to be something I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The **leaf level** of the Clustered index is the table.  You still have the other levels of the B-Tree  (root, intermediate) as a part of the clustered index which account for why there is an index for your PK on the table.

Answer (score -1):

A primary key is a logical concept.  When you create a primary key you are telling the DB that every row will be unique based on the columns specified in the primary key.  *How the DB enforces this uniqueness is up to the DB vendor*.

Microsoft has chosen to enforce the uniqueness of a primary key by creating a unique index.

Answer (score -2):

1. When you create Index or PK, SQL never creates a "File".
2. When you create PK, it will be clustered by default, unless you already have clustered index or specified PK as NON CLUSTERED.